# Google Map doesn't show up after move from test site to production (key was changed)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://barthumphries.com/apiary-map.html was my test site and it apparently works just fine.  I moved it over to http://gorderhoney.com/where-our-honey-comes-from.php and the map simply isn't showing up.  I tried setting the map to a static size, but still nothing.  I even remembered to change the API key.  On the gorderhoney site, the key is set to *.gorderhoney.com/*  The old API key doesn't work either.

Edit: Ok, fine, someone doesn't like the post.  But on https://developers.google.com/maps/support/ Google suggests that I use this site to ask for help.  I'd appreciate just getting the help instead of getting downvoted and ignored.  I would love to go elsewhere if there was some more official help forum to go to.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the key to gorderhoney.com/* as well.

Comment: Well, I voted for your comment -- I appreciate the help.  I don't know who's downvoting my post. I've gone over and over the code and I don't see what could be causing a problem.  I've now set the key to accept requests from:

\*.gorderhoney.com

\*.gorderhoney.com/\*

gorderhoney.com/\*

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Google Developer Page where you created the API key and find the option “Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)”. Next, you should add your website URL like this `example.com/*`. After doing so, the map will certainly show. I had the same issue in the past.

Comment: It may have just needed more time.  Every time I reloaded the website, tried to run it in an incognito browser or as a different user in Chrome, it threw up an error in the console.  But after I came back the next day, it all worked.